# Windows Phone 7 - Possible to Put Textbox in Application Bar?

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I want to create an application bar like IE has in Windows Phone 7.1 ... it has a textbox in it instead of buttons, and it still works as the application bar with menu items under it.

Is this possible.  I don't see anything under the Shell namespace, and just adding a Grid to the Application bar is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the application bar is not derived from `UIElement`. So you cannot add other UIElements to it.

The closest you can get is to add a `Grid` along the bottom of your phone screen, color it like the application bar and add a `TextBlock` to it. I wouldn't recommend this approach though, because it makes your app non-standard compared to all other apps available for the platform.

If you are to go this route, you can use the [`PhoneChromeBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) theme resource to set the color to match the application bar.